# How do I actually find a 'Stash' in a Saints Row reboot Threat

Tags: saints-row-2022

I've been playing through the saints row reboot. While I've generally *found* stashes, triggering off the waves of enemies, its entirely been either by accident, or by walking search lines within the highlighted circles (and sometimes *then* finding it by accident).

Is there some more 'obvious' sign to where a stash is that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I found a stash was through going up to doors, they aren’t highlighted or obvious, I kind of had to work that out myself, that’s how I found a stash anyway, you go up to it gain notoriety then a timer shows up.